# Macro to mark the duplicate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Please help I have lots of data that wan't to mark the first duplicate into the word duplicate and mark blank for the next duplicate.. I trying to use some formula but like "if" but not it is not working

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in C2,

```
=if(and(countif(a$2:a2, a2)=1, countif(a:a, a2)>1), "duplicate", "")
```

Fill down.